# Performance problems when changing tabs in WPF and using Telerik controls

Tags: wpf, performance, binding, telerik

We have a WPF application with tabs. Each tab is bound to a View model.

When we use WPF text boxes and select a tab we get a CPU spike of 7%, and the response is close to instantaneous.

When we use Telerik WPF controls and select a tab we get a CPU spike of 30% and the response time is 2 seconds.

Other info:

- There are about 30 text boxes on a tab
- We wrap the Telerik controls is a control
- We Rebind when we change tab
- We are running from Visual Studio in debug mode

Anyone have an idea of why we are seeing this poor performance and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

WPF unload items that are not visible, which includes TabItems that are not currently selected, so I suspect the performance hit when switching tabs is due to all the items on the new tab being re-loaded.

I usually use an extended version of the TabControl which stops it from unloading/reloading it's content when you switch tabs. The code is found [here](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/eburke/archive/2009/04/30/keeping-the-wpf-tab-control-from-destroying-its-children.aspx)